# Why JQuery's stopPropogation event is not working in this case?

Tags: jquery

I fail to understand why stop propogation is not working. I just want to disable the default behaviour of click event. If I replace it with return false it works! I am using jquery version 1.10.

```
           $("a[href^='/news']").click(function(evt){
                console.log('clicked');
                evt.stopPropagation();
                // return false; This works
            });// end click
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="news_center">
       <a href="/news">Breaking News</a>
    </div>
```

Pl. tell me where am I going wrong?

NOTE: Hi, I just wanted to check stop the event bubbling, I am more interested in finding out why stopPropogation is not stoping the bubble effect.

Thanks.

Comment: `return false;` in jquery equal `event.preventDefault(); event.stopPropagation();` You want to prevent default behaviour here

Comment: Hi Wolff, I have update the question, I wanted to check the event bubble behaviour with stopPropogation.

Comment: you are already stopping the event propagation. What makes you think it is not the case???

Comment: I am able to stop the event bubbling using event.preventDefault() but not with event.stopPropogation(), and that is what I wanted to know. Hope that clarifies my query?

Comment: event.preventDefault() doesn't stop event propagation, it prevents default behaviour which for an anchor click is to redirect to page targeted by attribute href.

Comment: Ok, so what does event.stopPropogation() do then?

Answer (score 0):

Try this [preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

```
evt.preventDefault();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zD7jB/)

Answer (score 0):

What you want isn't to *stop propagation* to the parent elements but to *prevent the default behavior*.

It's done using

```
evt.preventDefault();
```

And returning `false` prevents both propagation and the default behavior.

See [the MDN on preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault).

Comment: Hi, thanks, Actually I just wanted to check stop the event bubbling, I am more interested in finding out why stopPropogation is not stoping the bubble effect. I'll update the question.